# Create new gist with Github API v3 using curl

Tags: json, curl, github-api, gist

After fighting for quite some time for posting a private gist to Github using their API V3 I almost gave up. Almost. May be some one have also faced similar problem or know what might be the reasoning of the following behavior:

Right now the curl command looks like following:

```
curl -H "Authorization: bearer MY_AUTHORIZATION_TOKE" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"public":false,"files":{"test.txt":{"content":"String file contents"}}}' https://api.github.com/gists
```

I also tried

```
curl -H "Authorization: bearer MY_AUTHORIZATION_TOKE" -X POST -d '{"public":false,"files":{"test.txt":{"content":"String file contents"}}}' https://api.github.com/gists
```

I am able to create gist without authorization token using exactly same data:

```
curl -X POST -d '{"public":true,"files":{"test.txt":{"content":"String file contents"}}}' https://api.github.com/gists
```

But in that case it will be anonymous

Same results if I am truing to post it as public

In any case Github returns me

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
{
  "message": "Not Found"
}
```

I am pretty sure I am authorized, as `curl -H "Authorization: bearer MY_AUTHORIZATION_TOKE" https://api.github.com/user` returns me my user details.

Application scope is as:

https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?client_id=...&scope=gist

So, it should have both read and write permission.

Comment: Using a person auth token this worked for me no problem .

Answer (score 1):

Your OAuth2 token doesn't appear to have the required `gist` scope.

If you run the `curl` commands with the `-v` argument you can see the scope sent to request (`X-OAuth-Scopes` header) and the scope required for the request (`X-Accepted-OAuth-Scopes` header) to successfully be performed using the token sent.

If you don't see `gist` listed in the `X-OAuth-Scopes` header value then that is your problem.

Comment: In that case, as I menationed previously, you will post gist as Anonymous. Which is not the case.

Comment: What do you see for the values of the headers I mentioned when you run your command "curl -H "Authorization: bearer MY_AUTHORIZATION_TOKE" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"public":false,"files":{"test.txt":{"content":"String file contents"}}}' https://api.github.com/gists" with the -v curl argument?

Comment: Alternatively you can check `curl -u "username:password" https://api.github.com/authorizations`, if it has "gists" in the scopes array