# Upload a file to a Gist with bash

Tags: git, automation, github-api, gist

I usually paste error reports and logs on [Gist](https://gist.github.com) at Github, to exchange programming relevant debug information. Gist doesn't have a button to upload a file. So sometimes it is not so convenient to copy and paste your large errorreports into gists textarea for input.

Is there a way to upload a file from the commandline into a new Gist in your Gist account?

also creating a temporary git repository for the file to upload would help, I would automate this in a script then.

In the end I would like to automate posting debug information of my programming project on github with one bash script

Comment: Not a programming question, there's also a button that says "add file" on the page you link to.

Comment: This is a programming question, because gist is the biggest platform for Programmers. besides: there is an "Add File" button but that doesn't upload a file, it opens another textarea to **Paste** another file

Comment: I clarified the purpose of my question, please reconsider your votes

Comment: related: [How do you upload images to a gist?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16425770/how-do-you-upload-images-to-a-gist)

Comment: can you not use pastebinit to upload to gist?  https://bugs.launchpad.net/pastebinit/+bug/268287

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Here](https://gist.github.com/s-leroux/7cb7424d33ba3753e907cc2553bcd1ba) is a solution that works for me on Bash/Dash to create *anonymous* gist (very probably not bullet-proof):

```
# 0. Your file name
FNAME=some.file

# 1. Somehow sanitize the file content
#    Remove \r (from Windows end-of-lines),
#    Replace tabs by \t
#    Replace " by \"
#    Replace EOL by \n
CONTENT=$(sed -e 's/\r//' -e's/\t/\\t/g' -e 's/"/\\"/g' "${FNAME}" | awk '{ printf($0 "\\n") }')

# 2. Build the JSON request
read -r -d '' DESC <<EOF
{
  "description": "some description",
  "public": true,
  "files": {
    "${FNAME}": {
      "content": "${CONTENT}"
    }
  }
}
EOF

# 3. Use curl to send a POST request
curl -X POST -d "${DESC}" "https://api.github.com/gists"
```

If you need to create a gist associated with your github account, (for basic authentication) replace the last line by:

```
curl -u "${GITHUB_USERNAME}" -X POST -d "${DESC}" "https://api.github.com/gists"
```

For more advanced authentification schemes, please see https://developer.github.com/v3/#authentication

Comment: @Elric [Done !](https://gist.github.com/s-leroux/7cb7424d33ba3753e907cc2553bcd1ba)

Comment: I enhanced it a bit: https://gist.github.com/rubo77/3b8b15f4df5b5287a24f87523c41e4ce

Comment: There is one problem: if the file you are uploading contains a `%` character, it seems to break at that point: I tried to upload a file containing this: `UNIX_TIMESTAMP=$(date +%s%3N --date='TZ="UTC+2" '"$TIME")
`

Comment: @rubo77 Interesting. Right now, I can't see why `%` could have a special meaning. I don't know if I will have time to investigate that. Keep me informed if you have more ideas !

Comment: Why do you use gist for that? Lets move on with a repo that we can track its issues: https://github.com/ceremcem/create-gist

Comment: **sanitize** needs to be improved, code that contains literal `\n` becomes a newline in the uploaded gist, similar issues for literals `\t` and `\"`. Also commands that are spread over multiple lines with a trailing backslash `\ ` are not handled well. And scripts that also use the same `EOF` heredoc terminator are only partly uploaded.

Comment: To save people some time, go to directly to https://stackoverflow.com/a/68461779/610569 that provided an official github CLI usage.

Answer (score 11):

A command line tool implemented in Python:

```
pip install python-gist
gist create "example description" foo.txt bar.txt
```

See https://github.com/jdowner/gist

If you prefer a Ruby gem, see https://github.com/defunkt/gist

Comment: on Ubuntu:  `apt install gist` gives the gem.  I'm sure you can install with ruby if you prefer.  works like a gem :)

Answer (score 7):

Using the [GitHub CLI](https://github.com/cli/cli):

```sh
gh gist create yourfile
```

Or, for a public gist,

```sh
gh gist create --public yourfile
```

To add a description, use the `--desc`/`-d` flag, and to open directly in a web browser, use `--web`/`-w`.

See the [reference manual for `gh gist create`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_gist_create).

Comment: I like this, this is a newer answer :)

Answer (score 5):

Building on the answer of Sylvain Leroux, we can replace the sanitization and json building steps by making use of the [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) command line tool:

```
$ jq -Rs '{"description": "some description", "public": true, "files": {"'$FNAME'": {"content": .}}}' $FNAME | curl -X POST -d @- "https://api.github.com/gists"
```

Or, with authentication:

```
$ jq -Rs '{"description": "some description", "public": true, "files": {"'$FNAME'": {"content": .}}}' $FNAME | curl -u "${GITHUB_USERNAME}" -X POST -d @- "https://api.github.com/gists"
```

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to create a new Gist, using the [GitHub API for creating a Gist](https://developer.github.com/v3/gists/#create-a-gist):

```
POST /gists
```

You will find various script using this API, like:

- this [gist.el](https://github.com/defunkt/gist.el/blob/1d2a86de9b3ca2b2cfded4af0ad60926f61bfeca/gist.el#L127-L133) emacs function.
- this [php script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18667377/6309)
- this [`curl` command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10567899/6309)

Even the GitHub editor [Atom.io](https://atom.io/packages/gist-it) has a [gist-it feature](https://atom.io/packages/gist-it).

[image: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rpowelll/gist-it/master/media/screencast.gif]

Comment: Nice ;) But this doesn't explain how to do it with bash, is that possible?

Comment: @rubo77 yes: use the curl version I mention. It is a bash command.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://github.com/armsp/gifc) is a Python script to do the same. It is actively developed by me. The README is pretty straightforward in its usage details.
Some examples-

#### **Get a list of gists**

`gifc get 5`

#### **Create a gist**

- Create interactively from an editor like **nano**, **vim** or **gedit**

  - `gifc create create.md -d "How to create a gist from cli" -i nano`
- Directly enter contents from cli

  - `` gifc create create.md -d "How to create a gist from cli" -m '''If you want to create a gist from an existing file then you do the following-  `gifc create create.md -d "How to create a gist from cli" -f file.md`''' ``
- Take the contents from a file

  - `gifc create create.md -d "How to create a gist from cli" -f file.md`

#### **Update a gist**

- **Edit all (or some) files iteratively**

  - `gifc update ffd2f4a482684f56bf33c8726cc6ae63 -i vi`
    You can get the *gist id* from the `get` method from earlier
- **Change description**

  - `gifc update ffd2f4a482684f56bf33c8726cc6ae63 -cd "New description"`
    You can get the *gist id* from the `get` method from earlier
- **Edit contents of a file interactively in an editor like *nano*, *vim* or *gedit***

  - `gifc update ffd2f4a482684f56bf33c8726cc6ae63 -f file_to_update.md`
- **Do both**

  - `gifc update ffd2f4a482684f56bf33c8726cc6ae63 -f file_to_update.md -cd "New description"`

#### **Delete file(s) from a gist**

`gifc remove ffd2f4a482684f56bf33c8726cc6ae63 -r file1.md script.py readme.txt`
You can get the *gist id* from the `get` method from earlier

#### **Delete the whole gist**

`gifc delete ffd2f4a482684f56bf33c8726cc6ae63`
You can get the *gist id* from the `get` method from earlier

Answer (score 0):

For routers with limited busybox ash shells I created this [shell script post and patch gister](https://gist.github.com/ProBackup-nl/3971a45b21749cfff6c0069d3dad1dde). Usage: `$ pgist my_file_to_post_or_patch_to_gist.extension`

No need to remember long gist ID's. This gister is coded to automagically lookup the corresponding gist ID. Limitations are:

1. up to 30 (maybe 100) gists in your account
2. up to 300 files per gist
3. unique filenames for all your 30×300 gist files
4. it's not able to post/patch itself due to "*Problems parsing JSON*"

#### Installation example

`curl -O https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ProBackup-nl/3971a45b21749cfff6c0069d3dad1dde/raw/pgist.sh && chmod 755 pgist.sh && mv pgist.sh /opt/usr/sbin/pgist`

#### Dependencies

- [github oauth token](https://developer.github.com/v3/guides/getting-started/#oauth)
- `jq`
- `sed`
- `awk`
- `curl` and `ca-certificates` to create a valid certificate chain instead of

> (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate