# Create Github gist using file, with Gist API

Tags: shell, github, github-api, gist

I am attempting to make a github gist using the following command

```
curl -X POST -d '{"public":true,"files":{"test.txt":{"content":"String file contents"}}}' -u mgarciaisaia:mypassword https://api.github.com/gists
```

How should I edit the command such that it uploads a file on my local computer to the new gist, instead of taking content in a string from the command line?

Comment: Hi Norman, would [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26484337/upload-a-file-to-a-gist-with-bash) help you with your issue? It seems similar and the first answer might help you.

Answer (score 3):

You can use jq to generate a suitable payload. Let's say your file, `myfile`, looks like this:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

sed '
    s/://            # Drop colon
    s/^/Package: /   # Prepend with "Package: "
    N                # Append next line to pattern space
    s/\n/ | New: /   # Replace newline with " | New: "
    N                # Append next line to pattern space
    s/\n/ | Old: /   # Replace newline with " | Old: "
' updates.txt
```

A shell script with a sed command, including tab indentation, escaped characters and more. To convert this to a JSON string:

```sh
jq --raw-input --slurp '.' myfile
```

resulting in

```json
"#!/usr/bin/env bash\n\nsed '\n\ts/://            # Drop colon\n\ts/^/Package: /   # Prepend with \"Package: \"\n\tN                # Append next line to pattern space\n\ts/\\n/ | New: /   # Replace newline with \" | New: \"\n\tN                # Append next line to pattern space\n\ts/\\n/ | Old: /   # Replace newline with \" | Old: \"\n' updates.txt\n"
```

That's a single long string, safely escaped to be used as a JSON string.

Now, to get that into a format we can use as payload in the API call:

```sh
jq --raw-input --slurp '{files: {myfile: {content: .}}}' myfile
```

which prints

```json
{
  "files": {
    "myfile": {
      "content": "#!/usr/bin/env bash\n\nsed '\n\ts/://            # Drop colon\n\ts/^/Package: /   # Prepend with \"Package: \"\n\tN                # Append next line to pattern space\n\ts/\\n/ | New: /   # Replace newline with \" | New: \"\n\tN                # Append next line to pattern space\n\ts/\\n/ | Old: /   # Replace newline with \" | Old: \"\n' updates.txt\n"
    }
  }
}
```

or, for a public gist:

```sh
jq --raw-input --slurp '{public: true, files: {myfile: .}}' myfile
```

We can pipe this to curl and tell it to read the payload from standard input with `@-`:

```sh
jq --raw-input --slurp '{public: true, files: {myfile: .}}' myfile \
    | curl \
        https://api.github.com/gists \
        --header 'Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json' \
        --header "Authorization: token $(< ~/.token)" \
        --data @-
```

This uses a personal access token to authenticate, which is expected to be in the file `~/.token`.

---

If you use the [GitHub CLI](https://github.com/cli/cli), it becomes a lot simpler:

```sh
gh gist create --public myfile
```

and done!